# Swift: TableView didSelectRowAt Only Firing For Certain Rows?

Tags: swift

I am currently adding functionality to my Settings table view, and for some reason the table view didSelectRowAt function is only firing when I select the first row in each section.

I set up the table view using enum but I do not see why that would be causing the issue.

Here is my didSelectRowAtFunction:

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        guard let section = SettingsSections(rawValue: indexPath.section) else { return }
        guard let accountSection = AccountOptions(rawValue: indexPath.row) else { return }
        guard let financialSection = PaymentOptions(rawValue: indexPath.row) else { return }
        guard let communicationsSection = CommunicationsOptions(rawValue: indexPath.row) else { return }
        switch section {
        case .Account:
            switch accountSection {
                case .editAccountInfor:
                    print("Edit account pressed")
                case .logout:
                    print("logout pressed")
            }
        case .Communications:
            switch communicationsSection {
                case .notifacations:
                    print("notifs pressed")
            }
        case .Financial:
            switch financialSection {
                case .linkBankAccount:
                    print("LBA pressed")
                case .viewPaymentOptions:
                    print("payment options pressed")
            }
        }
    }
```

And it fires completely fine when I press the edit account information row, link bank account row or the notifications row. But when I press any of the rows that are not the first in the section, it does not display any statements.

Just in case it becomes necessary, here is my SettingsSections code along with AccountOptions to allow you guys to see how I have things set up.

```
enum SettingsSections: Int, CaseIterable, SectionType {
    case Account
    case Financial
    case Communications

    var containsSwitch: Bool {
        return false
    }
    
    var description: String {
        switch self {
        case .Account: return "Account"
        case .Financial: return "Financial"
        case .Communications: return "Communications"
        }
    }
}

enum AccountOptions: Int, CaseIterable, SectionType {
    case editAccountInfor
    case logout
    
    var containsSwitch: Bool {
        return false
    }
    var description: String {
        switch self {
        case .editAccountInfor: return "Edit Account Information"
        case .logout: return "Log Out"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the first line of the `didSelect` method, and observe what's happening. Hint: your sections each have a different number of rows, and you cannot expect all of those assignments to succeed.

Comment: Also, consider using breakpoints. Done strategically, you may find the issue. Maybe even consider "rebuilding" everything.... get a table view working, then use *one at a time* add everything.

Comment: @Gereon thank you, this helped understand the Swift interpretation of sections and rows within a table view. My question is then I suppose, what would be a better way to add actions on selection of a row?

Comment: Good option would be to get row in a section in the case corresponding to this section, that is when the value is valid.

Comment: Usually, two-dimensional arrays lend themselves well to be used as datasources for tableviews, since you can simply say `data[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]`. In your case however, it would be sufficient to move the "row" assignment into their corresponding `case` for their section.